# R function to search for potentially dead individuals in dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset with observations of individuals every day from 2015 to 2020. I want to ask R to give me "assumed dead" (individuals that haven't been seen for a year). Is there a function where I can ask who is assumed dead this month? For example I want to enter the month and the year and then R print me the list of all assumed dead this month (or at a specific date as I also have the date column).

Here is a subset of my dataset

```
BIRD_data = structure(
  list(
    ID = c(
      "FB37324",
      "FB37519",
      "FB37552",
      "FA72407",
      "FA42378",
      "FB37452",
      "FA42242",
      "FB37402",
      "FB37352",
      "FC10654",
      "FB37330",
      "FB37643",
      "FB37530",
      "FB37594",
      "FB37474",
      "FB37421",
      "FA42236",
      "FB37593",
      "FC10729",
      "FC10666"
    ),
    Name = c(
      "Rocket",
      "Dirkie",
      "Zumba",
      "Cake",
      "Hula",
      "Prickles",
      "Corsair",
      "Tigger",
      "Amarula",
      "Clapham",
      "Bidou",
      "Justin",
      "Pluto",
      "Sang",
      "Fawkes",
      "Cherry",
      "Hurricane",
      "Tan?",
      "Doobidoo",
      "Lucifer"
    ),
    Lring = c(
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "LB/ID",
      "ID",
      "",
      "ID",
      "DB/ID",
      "ID/WT",
      "MV",
      "LG",
      "",
      "DB/ID",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "ID",
      "ID/DB"
    ),
    Rring = c(
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "RD",
      "MV/LB",
      "",
      "O/BK",
      "WT",
      "O",
      "O/ID",
      "ID/MV",
      "",
      "YL",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "MV/DG",
      "DB"
    ),
    sex = c(
      "M",
      "F",
      "M",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "U",
      "M",
      "J",
      "M",
      "F",
      "M",
      "F",
      "F",
      "U",
      "F",
      "U",
      "J",
      "U"
    ),
    month = c(
      2L,
      1L,
      4L,
      12L,
      6L,
      3L,
      9L,
      8L,
      8L,
      6L,
      9L,
      7L,
      2L,
      4L,
      8L,
      10L,
      9L,
      9L,
      11L,
      8L
    ),
    year = c(
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2017L,
      2020L,
      2016L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2020L,
      2016L,
      2018L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2018L,
      2020L
    ),
    seen = c(
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L
    ),
    Freq = c(
      3L,
      9L,
      9L,
      11L,
      10L,
      3L,
      19L,
      14L,
      8L,
      4L,
      9L,
      9L,
      6L,
      7L,
      9L,
      6L,
      14L,
      17L,
      10L,
      5L
    ),
    day = c(
      "21",
      "8",
      "18",
      "1",
      "24",
      "5",
      "6",
      "26",
      "18",
      "5",
      "5",
      "1",
      "26",
      "19",
      "13",
      "20",
      "9",
      "30",
      "20",
      "5"
    ),
    location = c(
      "A",
      "S",
      "A",
      "S",
      "S",
      "A",
      "A",
      "A",
      "A",
      "S",
      "A",
      "S",
      "A",
      "A",
      "A",
      "A",
      "S",
      "A",
      "S",
      "SF"
    ),
    Date = structure(
      c(
        1487620800,
        1483819200,
        1429300800,
        1448913600,
        1498248000,
        1583352000,
        1473105600,
        1503691200,
        1.503e+09,
        1528142400,
        1536091200,
        1593547200,
        1456430400,
        1524081600,
        1471032000,
        1476907200,
        1473364800,
        1475179200,
        1542657600,
        1596571200
      ),
      tzone = "",
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-20L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function :

```
library(dplyr)

dead_birds <- function(data, date) {
  data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(last_seen =  as.Date(max(Date))) %>%
    filter(last_seen < date - lubridate::years(1)) %>%
    select(ID, Name, last_seen) %>%
    distinct()
}

result <- dead_birds(BIRD_data, as.Date('2019-12-01'))
```

Comment: It shows me this error message:

result <- dead_birds(BIRD_data, as.Date('01-02-2019'))
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘group_by’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’

Comment: You might have functions from other packages clashing. Try to add `dplyr::` in front of the functions. So `dplyr::group_by`, `dplyr::mutate` etc.

Comment: I also want to know the "assumed alive" so, every individual seen in the last 11 months.

I guess I just need to modify the "filter" line?

filter(last_seen <= date - lubridate::months(11)) %>% 

Is that correct?

Comment: I think you also need to make sure that `last_seen` is not greater than dates passed? Maybe use : `filter(between(last_seen, date - lubridate::month(11), date))`

Comment: Oh yes sure, thks! this works too no? :  filter(last_seen >= date - lubridate::months(11))

Comment: "Between" is a shortcut for x >= left & x <= right. But I want the individuals seen strictly superior to "date - year(1)", do you have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `last_seen > date - year(1)` ? Maybe you can add a new question if it is still confusing.

Comment: Yes sure, i'll use last_seen > date - year(1). Do you have any idea of how to keep the last known sex in the results? (one individual can be "juvenile/undertermined" one year and "male" the next year, I only want to keep "male" info in the results).

Comment: @Andre230 Please don't extend the question in comments. Ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_date <- as.Date('2020-12-01')
date_diff <- your_date - as.Date(BIRD_data$Date)
BIRD_data[date_diff>365,]
```

Comment: This will only give individuals who appeared one or more years ago. I think the correct logic is `with(BIRD_data, BIRD_data[date_diff > 365 & !ID %in% ID[date_diff <= 365]])` (appeared one or more years ago but not seen in this year)

Comment: yes you're right, I had a (wrong) assumption that each name is present only once on the table

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to look at the package for your "date_diff" function put I don't find it...

Comment: `date_diff` is not a function, it's a temporary variable created in the code - you don't need any package for it